# I am not able to link jquery file to my html

Tags: jquery, html

I am not able to find error in this code.
It's not linking properly with JQuery file.Please help.
Here's my html file:

```
 <html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='index.css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="F:\Rushikesh\Project\Final\index.js"></script>-->
</head>
<header>Web Development Tutorial</header>
    <body>.
        <div class="formDiv">
            <button  id="btn1">Submit</button><br />
            <p id="panelCnt">You have clicked submit button <span id="Cnt">0</span> times.</p>
        </div>                  
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is index.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btn1').click(alert("you clicked"));
});
```

Comment: you can't use local exist-only-on-your-harddrive links like that, especially if you're loading this via a webserver. And since that script block is commented out, you're not really linking to anything anyways.

Comment: You have included jQuery-UI. Please use this link to load jQuery - http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js

Comment: @MarcB I believe he's referring to the line above that.

Comment: Click handlers take a function.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to change your code. In HTML file, you have included "jquery-ui.js". Please use this link instead - code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js –  divyenduz

Which would make your code like this ( change in 4th line of code )

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='index.css'>
<script type="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<header>Web Development Tutorial</header>
    <body>.
        <div class="formDiv">
            <button  id="btn1">Submit</button><br />
            <p id="panelCnt">You have clicked submit button <span id="Cnt">0</span> times.</p>
        </div>                  
    </body>
</html>
```

The index.js file would change like, sending a anonymous function to click  :-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn1').click(function(){
        alert("you clicked");
    });
});
```

As well, welcome to StackOverflow community. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help to find out how to answer proper questions so as to avoid the down votes.

Thanks

Edit :- Check this - http://jsfiddle.net/ for working code